# Stellar chart with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I came across [this article](https://medium.com/nightingale/the-stellar-chart-an-elegant-alternative-to-radar-charts-ae6a6931a28e). I wonder if it is possible to make a **stellar chart** with Python? (see picture).
I have had a look at the `matplotlib` and `seaborn` galleries, but apparently they do not have any built in function to create such a chart (neither radar charts).

Is there any way to draw a chart like this easily using Python?

[image]

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/specialty_plots/radar_chart.html

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti This is a radar chart, but not a stellar (star) chart as shown in the picture. The article that I mentioned explains why radar charts can be problematic in many ways and this is why I wanted to build a star/stellar chart instead (see the article for more details). Still, I will have a look at the code that you mentioned to see if I can adapt it 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is a rendition of a `StellarChart`, as per your specifications.
It is derived from a `SpiderChart` (a `RadarChart`) build with `tkinter` to answer an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64862345/building-a-spider-chart-with-turtle-or-tkinter/64869175#64869175)

You can see them both side by side hereunder:

[image]

It takes a list of tuples('label', score), with the score expressed as a percentage (value in the interval [0, 100]).

The number of data points adjusts to the data provided.
The scale of the chart can be adjusted.

```
import math
import tkinter as tk


class SpiderChart(tk.Canvas):
    """a canvas that displays datapoints as a SpiderChart
    """
    width=500
    height=500
    def __init__(self, master, datapoints, concentrics=10, scale=200):
        super().__init__(master, width=self.width, height=self.height)
        self.scale = scale
        self.center = self.width // 2, self.height // 2
        self.labels = tuple(d[0] for d in datapoints)
        self.values = tuple(d[1] for d in datapoints)
        self.num_pts = len(self.labels)
        self.concentrics = [n/(concentrics) for n in range(1, concentrics + 1)]
        self.draw()
        
    def position(self, x, y):
        """use +Y pointing up, and origin at center
        """
        cx, cy = self.center
        return x + cx, cy - y
    
    def draw_circle_from_radius_center(self, radius):
        rad = radius * self.scale
        x0, y0 =  self.position(-rad, rad)
        x1, y1 =  self.position(rad, -rad)
        return self.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1, dash=(1, 3))
    
    def draw_label(self, idx, label):
        angle = idx * (2 * math.pi) / self.num_pts
        d = self.concentrics[-1] * self.scale
        x, y = d * math.cos(angle), d * math.sin(angle)
        self.create_line(*self.center, *self.position(x, y), dash=(1, 3))
        d *= 1.1 
        x, y = d * math.cos(angle), d * math.sin(angle)
        self.create_text(*self.position(x, y), text=label)
        
    def draw_polygon(self):
        points = []
        for idx, val in enumerate(self.values):
            d = (val / 100) * self.scale
            angle = idx * (2 * math.pi) / self.num_pts
            x, y = d * math.cos(angle), d * math.sin(angle)
            points.append(self.position(x, y))
        self.create_polygon(points, fill='cyan')
        
    def draw(self):
        self.draw_polygon()
        for concentric in self.concentrics:
            self.draw_circle_from_radius_center(concentric)
        for idx, label in enumerate(self.labels):
            self.draw_label(idx, label)
            
            
class StellarChart(SpiderChart):
    """a canvas that displays datapoints as a StellarChart
    """        
    def draw_polygon(self):
        points = []
        da = math.pi / self.num_pts
        b = .05 * self.scale
        for idx, val in enumerate(self.values):
            d = (val / 100) * self.scale
            angle = idx * (2 * math.pi) / self.num_pts
            x, y = d * math.cos(angle), d * math.sin(angle)
            points.append(self.position(x, y))
            xb, yb = b * math.cos(angle + da), b * math.sin(angle+da)
            points.append(self.position(xb, yb))
        self.create_polygon(points, width=3, outline='red', fill='pink', join=tk.ROUND)

            
data = [('stamina', 70), ('python-skill', 100), ('strength', 80), ('break-dance', 66), ('speed', 45), ('health', 72), ('healing', 90), ('energy', 12), ('libido', 100)]

root = tk.Tk()

stellar = StellarChart(root, data)
stellar.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

spider = SpiderChart(root, data)
spider.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: That's a very interesting approach, I will have a closer look at Tkinter. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The Plotly library includes a starchart: https://plotly.com/python/radar-chart/

Comment: The Plotly library includes a radar chart, but not a stellar (star) chart as shown in the picture. The article that I mentioned explains why radar charts can be problematic in many ways and this is why I wanted to build a star/stellar chart instead (see the article for more details).